# Mouse over area as a polygon in html

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I need to have an area for which I would set mouse over event. How can I do that in JavaScript?

This area should be

- easy to define
- invisible (i need the background to be visible).

Comment: Image maps come to mind. They are 10000 years old, but probably still work.

Answer (score 0):

To make an svg shape(polygon,rect,circle,path) invisible, the fill attribute is set to "none". And to make it still respond to events you include pointer-events="visible". Then you include a mouseover event within the shape. Note: 
**evt** is the svg event object call. The function itself can also apply outside of the element(target) to which it is attached. For example, the function could draw a circle anywhere in the svg root.

e.g.

```
<svg id="mySVG" width="400" height="400">
<rect id="myRect" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" pointer-events="visible"  fill="none" onmouseover="myEvent(evt)" />
</svg>

<script>
    function myEvent(evt)
    {
       var target=evt.target
       target.setAttribute("fill","red")
    }
</script>
```